# What is the correct algorithm to return all combination of elements where i<j<k

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I have to find all the combinations in an array a[] with indices i,j,k such that i<j<k and have to perform one operation for every combination
for example in an array
int a[] = {12,1,34,32}
the combination are
{12,1,34},{12,1,32},{12,34,32}.{1,34,32}

I have tried recursive way and storing all the combinations in a set so that if I visit the same combination again I will return from there only by checking it from the set

my code is this but i am getting TLE for large cases
can anyone please provide me the most efficient way for this

```
 static Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
 static int sum = 0;

    static void solve(int i,int j,int k,int[] a){
        if(i>=j || j>=k ||k>=a.length){
            return;
        }
        
        //combination
        String pre = String.valueOf(i)+String.valueOf(j)+String.valueOf(k);
        if(set.contains(pre)){
            return;
        }

        //operation to perform for every combination
        int v = (a[i] | a[j] | a[k]) ^ (a[i] ^ a[j] ^ a[k]);
        sum = sum+v;

        solve(i,j,k+1,a);
        solve(i,j+1,k,a);
        solve(i+1,j,k,a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For three indices it is simpler to make three loops. Also I added precalculation of two binary operations and removed set check for simplicity.

```
static int solve(int[] a){
    int leng = a.length;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i=0; i < leng-2; i++)   {
       for (j=i+1; j < leng - 1; j++)   {
           int ijor = a[i] | a[j];
           int ijxor = a[i] ^ a[j];
           for (k=j+1; k < leng; k++)   {
              //operation to perform for every combination
             sum = sum + (ijor | a[k]) ^ (ijxor ^ a[k]);
           }
        }
     }
     return sum; 
}
```

Comment: But this is a brute force solution, wouldn't this will give me the n3 time complexity

Comment: Yes, but you have not explained real problem, just wrote your function

Comment: Ok sorry for that, Actually I have to return the sum of operation given by all the different combinations under the given condition i <j<k  (the operation I have mentioned inside the code)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using java, however, I'm able to provide an answer with python but I'm sure that there are equivalent operations in java too:

```
from itertools import combinations
def combs_tri(X):
    lenght=len(X)
    num_of_zeros=lenght-3
    def factorial(n):
        m=1
        for x in range(1,n+1):
            m=m*x
        return m
    def num_of_comb(n,z):
        return int(factorial(lenght)/(factorial(z)*factorial(lenght-z)))
    count=num_of_comb(lenght,3)
    def create_boolean_array(num_of_zeros,count,lenght):
        Arr=np.zeros((count,lenght))
        combs=list(combinations(range(lenght), 3))
        for i,comb in enumerate(combs):
            Arr[i,comb]=1
        return Arr
    repeated_list=np.repeat([X],count,axis=0)
    bool_mask=create_boolean_array(num_of_zeros,count,lenght)
    return repeated_list[bool_mask.astype(bool)].reshape((int(count)),3)
```

[image]

### Function Explanations

factorial:Executes the mathemetical operation factorial which is n!=n(n-1)*(n-2)*...

num_of_comb:Executes the mathematical combination operation and returns the numerical result.

create_boolean_array: Creates an boolean mask to get all possible combinations of array ellements.
->combinations(): returns combinations
Ex/ combinations([1,2,3],2)=[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]

->np.repeat([X],count,axis=0) repeats the given list by given count number. Count number means number of combinations (for 3) in here.

Ex/ np.repeat([1,2,3,4],count,axis=0)=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])

---

In most cases array operations are much faster than for loops.

Comment: Hello Hakan can you please explain your code like your approach, which functions are doing what. It will really be helpful

Comment: I've tried to explain it but if you have more questions you can ask it again

Comment: I have some more doubts like, why you calculate factorial what is its importance, I do not understand the working of num_of_comb function and how this will help? then in create_boolean_array function what is np, np.zeros .  ?  Like I want to know the main concept and thinking behind this solution              Thank You

Comment: np.zeros creates an array of zeros for example np.zeros(4,4) creates a 4,4 array filled with 0s. and by changing some indexes into 1 we can use boolean logic. 0s means false, 1 means trues. In python's numpy library by using boolean logic you can extract elements just with trues, hence 1s. num_of_comb is needed in order to  know how many times a given list must be repeated(used in repeated_list part) also it's needed in boolean array creation.

Comment: The main concept is creating array of given list by repeating it. Imagine a given list is a row and it's repeated as much as number of combinations as the number of column numbers. After having such an array by using boolean logic you can extract possible combinations bu creating an array of 0s and 1s. As en example given list is [1,2,3,4] repated_list is [[1,2,3,4] ,[1,2,3,4] ,[1,2,3,4] ,[1,2,3,4] ], boolean mask is [[0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,0]]. As you can see as we use the mask we have [[2,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,3]]. So this is the essence behind the idea. I hope it was clear

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a really simple problem with just 3 loops. I wrote code in c++, but you will surely understand it:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void print_all(const std::vector<int>& arr){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size() - 2; i++) {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < arr.size() - 1; j++) {
            for (size_t k= j + 1; k < arr.size(); k++) {
                if ((arr[i] < arr[j]) || (arr[i] > arr[j] && arr[i] < arr[k]))
                    std::cout << "[" << arr[i] << "," << arr[j] << "," << arr[k] << "]\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr = {12, 1, 34, 32};
    print_all(arr);
}
```

For the condition, for a tuple `(a, b, b)`:

1. if `a<b`, then you can select any `c` and reach `a<b<c` with 1 move at max.
2. if `a>b`, the you need to switch them, then all `c` need to bigger than `a`.